# RDLC Report Background Image Assignment Issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I want to assign specific image to my RDLC report,so that receipt should generate with background image with proper alignment,header and data should print to specific area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a background image, do the following:

1. Open the client report definition (.rdlc) file in graphical design mode.
2. Select the report item to which you want to add a background image.
3. In the Properties window, expand BackgroundImage, and then do the following:
   -For Source, select External, Embedded, or Database.
   -For Value, type or select an expression that evaluates to the source of the image.

   - If the Source property is set to External, the expression must evaluate to a valid path to an     image. This can be a static path
     to an image hosted on a report server, or it can be a path based on 
     a field. If the image is stored in the project, type the name of the
     image as it appears in the project.
   - If the Source property is set to Embedded, the expression must evaluate to the name of an image that is embedded in the report. If
     the Source property is set to Database, the expression must evaluate
     to a field that contains binary image data.

   -For MIMEType, select the appropriate MIME type for the image.